# Using jQuery to change the background image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the background image of a link when it get clicked.  I keep getting the error that you cannot call 'click' on null.

JQuery (in the header)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a.upvote-arrow').click(function(){
        $('#tempid1').css('background-image','url(../images/icons/up-arrow2.png)');
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="top-comment-vote">
    <a href="#" class="upvote-arrow" title="Up vote" id="tempid1"></a>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `$(document).ready`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.upvote-arrow').click(function(){
        $(this).css('background-image','url(../images/icons/up-arrow2.png)');
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  I did that I now I got an 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input'

Comment: thanks, got it to work, the problem was that the '$' was conflicted, so I had to do `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();`.  Thanks, it now works!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this script is being loaded after the html is in the DOM?

Try wrapping what you wrote in a onload closure.

```
$(function() {
 $('a.upvote-arrow').click(function(){
   $('#tempid1').css('background-image','url(../images/icons/up-arrow2.png)');
 });
});
```

Another thing you can do is take advantage of delegation for the event registration.

```
$('body').on("click", ".a.upvote-arrow", function(){
 $('#tempid1').css('background-image','url(../images/icons/up-arrow2.png)');
});
```

This binds it to the body instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your script with document.ready; I suspect that you're script might be running before your entire page loads.